# Postgres-Changing time format from 24 hour to 12 hour?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I've copied data into a table called Yseriesdata, this was done using COPY (...) FROM (...).

Everything has imported successfully with one small discrepancy, the "measurementdt" value (of type 'timestamp without time zone') inside the CSV file are in a 12 hour format.

The first date is "5/26/2016  12:00:00 AM" in the CSV while the first value in measurementdt column is "2016-05-26 00:00:00" in my pg DB. Is their a way to remedy this such that the value will be identical with value in the CSV file?

Comment: I should say that the "measurementdt" column in the postgresql DB is defined as  timestamp without time zone, the CSV date values are simply 12 hour YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format..

Comment: select   to_char(measurementdt, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH12:MI AM') from  yourtable;    -- ??